# What goes inside "trunk" folder in SVN?

Tags: svn, version-control, naming-conventions

This is a very basic and kind of meaningless question, but nevertheless:

Should I put the contents of my solution directly into the `trunk` directory, or in `trunk/Solution`?

I've done a search but could not find what is the accepted "convention" for this.

Comment: https://www.visualsvn.com/support/svnbook/reposadmin/planning/

Comment: "If you have only one project per repository, the logical place to put each project root is at the root of that project's respective repository." - That means Option #1 of my question? Just to be sure.

Comment: If you plan to have only one project in your repository, place the solution to /trunk. If you plan to have multiple projects, place it under /trunk/projectname. It does not really matter unless you plan to have many projects in one repository.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This really has nothing to do with Subversion (or any other version control).

Ask yourself this question: If I create a directory tree to contain everything version-dependent to do with the project I am working on, how would I organise it? By “project” I mean the activity, not what MSVS calls a project. By “version-dependent” I mean anything that belongs under version control, i.e. that varies from one version to the next and is needed to produce your deliverables. You should be able to copy that tree to another computer with the necessary tools installed (just MSVS?) and carry on where you left off. Whatever goes in the root of that tree goes in the `trunk` directory.

If the only file in the root is the directory `Solution`, you might feel that looked a bit unnecessary — if that is the way you feel, don’t do that. And don’t worry about getting it right from the start: if it turns out inconvenient, moving files and directories around in Subversion is pretty easy (though Tortoise makes it a little hard to find by hiding it under the not very well known right-drag mouse gesture).

You might find yourself putting other stuff in your working copy, such as user and internal documentation — then you would probably want the code base a level down.